# Tight VNC on Windows Server16

Tags: windows, vnc, tightvnc

I am no means Windows fella, but due to circumstances have to configure sikuli test suite on Windows Server 2016.
The problem I have is that i have installed Tight VNC on it, and when connect to the running VNC server on that Windows Server 2016 instance from Mac VNC Viewer i get login prompt and then after entering the password black screen and it just stays black. RDP does work. Any things i am missing in setup?
Thank you.

Comment: Why not just use RDP? You can get the Microsoft RDP client free in the Mac App Store.

Comment: I need to run sikuli in headless mode, i didn't find any solution using RDP.

Comment: That doesn't matter. You can use RDP even if the server has a GUI or is server core. Or you can use PowerShell remoting. But this is irrelevant to the application you might run.